# How to edit registry with cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, windows-registry

I want to edit the start type from a service with command prompt.

For example delivery-optimisation-service :

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\InstallService\DoSvc
```

My goal is to create a bat file that will allow me to set the start value from the service.

Value 4 for disabled and value 3 for manually.

I guess the command must look similar to this:

```
reg edit HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\InstallService\DoSvc \Start \value_4
```

Obviously this command is wrong, anyone please let me know what the correct command is?

Comment: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-edit-registry-using-command-prompt-windows-10

Comment: Why would you be editing the registry?.  `sc config dosvc start= disabled`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `reg edit` command, you should use the documented
[reg add](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-add):

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\InstallService /v Start /t REG_BINARY /d 4
```

Comment: No, like i said i want to edit an existing registry entry, i want to edit the start value. I dont want to add a key.

Comment: That's then the misunderstanding - you don't need to edit, you just set it. An existing value is just replaced.

Answer (score 0):

To set the value to 4 try this code. The net session part makes sure the batch runs as admin since you need admin rights to change the value. Also you would have to use the /f switch so the command doesn't ask for confirmation if you want so override the existing value.

```
@echo off
net session >nul 2>&1 || (powershell start -verb runas '"%~0"' &exit /b)

reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DoSvc" /v Start /t reg_dword /d 4 /f
```

Comment: thank you, this appears to be working. exactly what i needed, thank you very much. the term /f means run as admin is that correct? i am not familiar with all those commands such as /v /f /t /b etc. Where can i find a documentation on this? Any useful site explaining how this works? Im also woondering about this one '"%~0"'

Comment: /f for "force" otherwise you would get a confirmation request "do you want to substitute the value?". To see all options you could use reg add /? in the command prompt. %~0 means full path of the batch script